# Getting exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError : org.aspectj.weaver.patterns.IScope

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-aop

I am running a Web Portlet project with Spring MVC framework. I am trying to do Auditing with the help of AOP. but when i am running the application i am getting 2 exceptions at different points...
1st when i am trying to just build the project i am getting

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.aspectj.weaver.patterns.IScope
```

and when publishing the project on Web sphere portal server getting :

```
Uncaught service() exception root cause AuditProject: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.InstantiationException: javax.portlet.GenericPortlet
```

I have also included aspectweaver jar. but still getting the same exception.
Someone please suggest me something on this

Comment: recheck all the dependencies (libraries) for `NoClassDefFoundError` .

Comment: explode your .war file and check if this dependency is there in the library

Comment: @NikhilTalreja: War file also has this jar file. Is there any other issue?

Comment: Whats the version for the jar?

Comment: @NikhilTalreja aspectjweaver-1.7.4

Answer (score 0):

have you added all your libraries as external libraries ? If you are using eclipse then just right click the project -> properties -> java build path -> libraries (column name) -> add external jars 
Now select the jar files you want to add in the project.

Comment: i have added aspectweaver jar in that way only. But still getting the same exception.